# Запись в массив из строки

Tags: c

Каким образом можно записать разделенную строчку в двумерный массив, я что-то так и не додумал.

```c
void processing()
{

    FILE *file = fopen(FNAME, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Ошибка при открытии исходного файла");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t counter = 0;
    int ch, pre = EOF;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        pre = ch;
        if (ch == '\n')
            ++counter;
    }

    if (pre == EOF)
    {
    }
    else if (pre != '\n')
    {
        ++counter;
    }

    char tableInfo[counter][2];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    char neObrabotInfo[256];
    char sep[10] = ":";
    char *istr;

    file = fopen("BookContact.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Ошибка при открытии исходного файла");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("\n\nFile opened successfully\n\n");

    while (fgets(neObrabotInfo, 256, file))
    {
        istr = strtok(neObrabotInfo, sep);

        while (istr != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", istr);
            istr = strtok(NULL, sep);
            tableInfo[0][0] = istr;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d",tableInfo[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;

    fclose(file);
}
```

Не получается запихнуть разобранную строку в массив
Строки которые разбираются, пропуская `":"`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на выходе получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно записать в двумерный массив чтоб массив выглядел так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текстовую информацию нужно предоставлять в текстовом виде, а не картинках. Что делать тем, кто захочет вам помочь? Перенабирать тестовые строки вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы записывать в массив `tableInfo` строки, его элементы должны иметь тип `char*`, а не просто `char`:

```
char * tableInfo[counter][3];
```

Так как буфер (в котором хранятся строки) перезаписывается на каждой итерации, для сохранения строк нужно выделять новую память и копировать их туда, а указатели на эти копии уже сохранять в `tableInfo`. Например так:

```
for (i = 0; fgets(neObrabotInfo, 256, file); i++) {
    istr = strtok(neObrabotInfo, sep);
    for (j = 0; istr != NULL; j++) {
        tableInfo[i][j] = malloc(strlen(istr) + 1);
        strcpy(tableInfo[i][j], istr);
        istr = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
}
```